# Parse CSV in Python

Tags: python

I am trying to run the below code to open a csv, parse the rows and print the output in my terminal

```
import csv
with open('C:\Users\Python\test7.csv') as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=',')
    line_count = 0
    for row in csv_reader:
        print(row)
```

When I run this script in my terminal, it completes with now errors.It instead just opens the python code in my text editor and does not spit out the information from the csv. Is something formatted incorrectly in my code?

Comment: What command are you using to run the script from the terminal? `./script.py`?

Comment: Have you verified that other Python programs do _not_ just open the code in your text editor? Because that sounds more like a problem with your environment than with this specific program.

Comment: Prefix the command you're running from the terminal with `python `. Alternatively you can put a path to the python interpreter at the top of your script like: `#!/usr/bin/env python`. More information here: `https://www.pythoncentral.io/execute-python-script-file-shell/`

Comment: [Should I put #! (shebang) in Python scripts, and what form should it take?](//stackoverflow.com/q/6908143)

Comment: dont put shebangs, call python, why would they have execution permission?

Comment: I am using ./script.py to run the script

Comment: What operating system are you using?

Comment: `./script.py` does not execute the script, it simply opens it in your default application for opening `.py` files. Apparently your default application is a text editor. But anyway, this is probably a question for SuperUser rather than SO.